# assigning a char variable two values?

Tags: java, variables, char

This is what I want to happen:

```
 char mirrorWords='x'||'w';
```

what I want to do with this is:

```
mirrorWords=='u'
```

returns false.

and

```
mirrorWords=='x'
```

returns true.

and

```
mirrorWords=='w'
```

returns true.

if this is possible how do I do it? And if not, well... thank you for your time.

update: I don't know why this is closed... I already accepted an answer.

Comment: Why would `mirrorWords == 'y'` return true? Also you can just do `mirrorWords == 'w' || mirrorWords == 'x'` which will return true if either conditions is true

Comment: No, a character variable holds just one character.

Comment: It's unclear what you really want to happen.

Comment: @GBlodgett because mirrorWords equals y or w so if you ask "does mirrorWords equal y?" the answer is yes because it is either

Comment: @sandroHakimArrangements In your example it *doesn't* equal `y`

Comment: @MickMnemonic how might I go about fixing it? (what is unclear)

Comment: @GBlodgett yes you are right, I fixed it

Comment: So you want to _assign_ a variable either one character value _or_ another? How could that possibly work? Which value would be assigned and based on which criteria? If you want to assign one character _and_ another, you need to use `char[]` or a `String`. Also, why would you need this? This sounds like a possible [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @MickMnemonic I feared that, thankyou.

Comment: why was this put on hold i already accepted an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot store more than one character in a single variable. However when you do the comparison you can do:

```
 mirrorWords == 'w' || mirrorWords == 'x'
```

which will return `true` if either conditions is true, which sounds like what you want